# Problem when discovering an emulated roku (on HA) from a Harmony Hub

Tags: smart-home, home-assistant, logitech-harmony

*This question also lives in the [HA forum](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/problem-when-discovering-an-emulated-roku/87733) and [r/homeassistant on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/homeassistant/comments/a9mmm7/is_it_possible_to_access_ha_actions_from_a/)*

I run HA on `10.10.1.1` (this is a container) and my WiFi is on `10.10.2.0/24`. To this WiFi is connected a Harmony Hub.

Following a [writeup](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/unable-to-setup-emulated-roku/55785/7?u=wojwoj) by [@chubby92](https://community.home-assistant.io/u/chubby92/summary), I wanted to set up an emulated roku which would be configured on the Harmony  Hub.

I believe that the Harmony Hub is scanning the network it is on looking for open `8060` ports so I set up a `socat` proxy on a device which is on the WiFi network (`10.10.2.5`) to bridge it with the HA container.

```
root@10.10.2.5 ~# socat TCP4-LISTEN:8060 TCP4:10.10.1.1:8060
```

This works fine (from any machine on the network):

```xml
root@srv ~# curl http://10.10.2.5:8060
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0">
    <specVersion>
        <major>1</major>
        <minor>0</minor>
(...)
```

I therefore expected the Harmony Hub to now detect the emulated roku but I get an error, which says that *Roku Roku 1 is not discoverable* (or *found*, it depends on the context of the translation, my locale is French). It suggest to check that both devices are on the same WiFi (they are - indirectly) and proposes to either search again or ignore the IP analysis. Ignoring it adds the device but I have serious doubts it will work - I would like to be sure this is the expected outcome before digging in further.

UPDATE: yes, it does not seem to work. I listen to the HA events bus (by listening on all events in AppDaemon) and I do not see anything when choosing "Roku 1" on the Harmony remote, and trying to send something (say, Page Up, which is one of the first ones available)